# Error in Lua script for add page in Ti nspire CX CAS

Tags: lua

I have reviewed a lot of the documentation about the Lua API for the Ti-nspire calculator and I can not find a way to add a page using code.
Does anyone know how to do it. Thank you

Comment: Did you check that ? https://education.ti.com/html/webhelp/EG_TINspireLUA/EN/index.html

Comment: Or even that : https://wiki.inspired-lua.org/Main_Page